# Jquery "if this and if that" then do this

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

This should be so simple, but it's not working for me. I want to say:

If this doesn't have the class "current" AND if the body class does not equal "home", then do this....

Here is what I'm trying (among other things) to no avail. Only the first conditional works.

```
$(".nav1 > ul > li").mouseleave(function() {

    if ( (!$(this).hasClass("current")) || (!$(body).hasClass("home"))  ){
         $(this).find(".nav-overlay").show();   
    }

});
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

UPDATE FOR CLARITY:

I only want to show ".nav-overlay" when the following conditions are true:

1. You are not on the homepage (body class="home") 
   AND
2. The ".nav1 > ul > li" class does not equal "current"

Comment: `||` means "or". `&&` means "and".

Comment: You are saying "class does not equal"; you mean the entire value of the class attribute? This will test for 1 specific class value in the collection of classes.

Comment: For some reason, the && only works on the homepage. So when the body class="home", it correctly ignores the function. However, on an interior page when the body class="anythingelse" and the li class="current" - then it doesn't ignore the function.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try `$("body")` and `&&`:

```
   if ( (!$(this).hasClass("current")) && (!$("body").hasClass("home"))  ){
    //...
```

Or this way , it is shorter:

```
   if ( !$(this).is(".current") && !$("body").is(".home")  ){
     //...
```

Answer (score 4):

If `body` is **not** a variable, access it as a HTML tag: add quotes. Also, `AND` is `&&` instead of `||` (that means `OR`):

```
if (!$(this).hassClass("current") && !$("body").hasClass("home")) {
    $(this).find(".nav-overlay").show();
}
```

If `body` is a jQuery object you can do directly `... && !$body.hashClass(...)`.

Comment: `body` might be a variable, there is not much context though.

Comment: Thank you. I was incorrectly using the || and also, as @Cherniv suggested, using the .is instead of .hasClass, seemed to fix it.