# Alert if there's a click in a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I want to alert if there's a click in a specific div.

Scenario:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="header"> <h1>Headline<h1> </div>
<div class="productbox"></div>
</div>
```

I know how to alert Headline...

```
$("h1:contains('Headline')").one( function() {
alert("ALERT Headline");
});
```

...and how to alert Productbox

```
$(".productBox").click(function){ 
alert("ALERT Productbox click");
});
```

Now I want to "marry" these two.

My code:

```
if (!$("h1:contains('Headline')").one(function) && !$(".productBox").click(function)){
alert:("Alert when h1 contains Headline and ProductBox is clicked")};
```

Taken from: [Jquery "if this and if that" then do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216291/jquery-if-this-and-if-that-then-do-this)

Sidenote: There's no unique selectors (elements nor IDs that I could use), that's why I figured to use the Headline.

**Although "headline" is not directly above class productBox**

Comment: `:contains()` is a very fragile and expensive selector. A class or id would be better.

Comment: you should know `click` is an event and the function in there is only called when someone actually clicks. the rest of the code is executed when  the code starts right, remember this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should know `click` is an event and the function in there is only called when someone actually clicks. the rest of the code is executed when  the code starts right, remember this.

Your code contains these semantic parts:

- Assigning an on click handler: when somone clicks this function is fired.
- checking if an H1 with content `Headline` exists
- Firing an alert if so.
- point 2 and 3 should only be fired when a someone clicks (so when the click handler is fired)

your code:

```
//Registering an on click handler, code inside here fires whe someone clicks
$(".productBox").click(function(){ 
  //check if headline exists in your code (i prefer checking with length, since it returns a jquery array of found elements for this selector)
  if ( $("h1:contains('Headline')").length == 1 )
  {
    //alert user if so
    alert("Alert when h1 contains Headline and ProductBox is clicked");
  }
});
```

### about jQuery one()

http://api.jquery.com/one/

one is kind of the same function as click: but only the handler will fire once. you could use it like this:

```
//Registering a click handler that only fires once, code inside here fires whe someone clicks
$(".productBox").one("click",function(){ 
  //check if headline exists in your code (i prefer checking with length, since it returns a jquery array of found elements for this selector)
  if ( $("h1:contains('Headline')").length == 1 )
  {
    //alert user if so
    alert("Alert when h1 contains Headline and ProductBox is clicked");
  }
});
```

Comment: It could be fired multiple times in a session though

Answer (score 2):

Your event should be on ProductBox only, and inside that you need to check for the prev element's condition.

```
$(".productBox").click(function(){ 
 if ( $(this).prev().find("h1:contains('Headline')").size() > 0 )
 {
   alert("Alert when h1 contains Headline and ProductBox is clicked");
 }
});
```

Comment: $(".productBox").click(function){ 
 if ( $(this).find("h1:contains('Headline')"))
 {
   alert("Alert when h1 contains Headline and ProductBox is clicked");
 }
});

Comment: @Hbaecklund No, since productbox doesn't have child h1, its prev sibling has

Comment: how come you add .size?

Comment: @Hbaecklund because find() will return a list of jquery objects

Comment: @gurviner372 I only receive syntax error, will re-formulate question

Comment: @Hbaecklund check updated code, syntax error should not be there.

Comment: Although "headline" is not directly above class productBox